# Unix Split Function ~ select 2 different split words

Tags: cut

I am using `cut -d' ' -f1`  to split a string in unix scripts. I want only f1 and f5, though, and I'm unable achieve this.

I tried giving `-f1-5`, but that prints all the fields from 1st through 5th.

Answer (score 3):

```
cut -d' ' -f1,5
```

From `man cut`

```
-f, --fields=LIST
       select only these fields
```

Then later

```
Each LIST is made up of one range, or many ranges separated by commas.
```

Answer (score 1):

awk can help:

`echo "10 20 30 40 50" |awk '{print $1,$5}'`

or

`awk '{print $1,$5}' file.txt`

You can even modify the results in place:

`echo "10 20 30 40 50" |awk '{print $1*$5}'`
--> 500

(`awk` is `cut` on steroids)

Comment: To replicate the question options, you'd also need `-F' '`.